# Adding custom game logic to Scene Kit (Swift)

Tags: ios, loops, swift, scenekit

I need to add a game loop to my GameViewController (From the Swift "Game" template for iOS development) in order to create an application and found this reference page explaining how to do this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/

However when I try to set the delegate of the SCNView to be the ViewController it throws up warnings and errors (inside viewDidLoad()):

```
gameView.delegate = self
```

Where gameView is connected to an SCNView in my storyboard:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gameView: SCNView!
```

It would be brilliant if someone could link a code example of setting up game logic using Swift and Scene Kit or explain it to me from the ground up. Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to diagnose your problem if you don't say *which* warnings and errors you're seeing. (Possibly your `ViewController` doesn't declare conformance to the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` protocol?)

Comment: How would I go about declaring conformance to the SCNSceneRendererDelegate protocol?

Comment: See [Protocol Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_403) in the Swift book: `class ViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, OtherProtocolsEtc`

Comment: I take it that was the problem, so let's move the solution to an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign:

```
gameView.delegate = self
```

This requires that `self` be a class that declares conformance to the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` protocol. To make your view controller class declare protocol conformance, use the syntax described [in the Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_403):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate  {
    //                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
    //                ^- superclass     ^- protocol              |
    //                   more protocols if you conform to them --/ 

    // ... rest of class definition ...
}
```

Comment: This is some sexy ASCII. How did you do this without going insane with tabs and spaces?