# 3rd Person Camera in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, camera, scenekit, scnnode

I need to attach a `SCNCamera` to a `SCNNode` so that whenever the node (ball) moves, the camera follows it.

So far I managed to do it by constantly moving the camera when physics is updated, but its not very efficient and has some delay.

```
    func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact)
    {
        var cameraP = SCNVector3(x: ball.presentationNode().position.x, y: ball.presentationNode().position.y + 5, z: ball.presentationNode().position.z + 12)
        camera.constraints = nil
        camera.position = cameraP
        camera.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: ball)]
    }
```

I read some information about `SCNTransformationConstraint` that could "attach" the camera to the node but I found no working example.

I can't just attach the camera to the node as I want to adjust the position of the camera.

Thanks.

Edit: (To Moustach)

I tried to do that using:

```
optional func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: NSTimeInterval)
{
    println("called")
}
```

but I get an error saying: `Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'rendered' has no keyword argument name`

**Edit 2 (working):**

With Moustach's advice, we were able to make this work efficiently.

The camera position is now updated on:

```
func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: NSTimeInterval)
{
    println("called")
}
```

Furthermore, a new `SCNNode` was created as a rootNode of the camera node to hold its position.

Setting up the camera now looks like this:

```
        let lookAtBallConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: ball)
        lookAtBallConstraint.gimbalLockEnabled = true

        let tempCam = SCNCamera()
        tempCam.zFar = 5000
        camera = SCNNode()
        camera.camera = tempCam
        camera.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        camera.constraints = [lookAtBallConstraint]

        cameraPosition = SCNNode()
        cameraPosition.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 5, z: 12)
        cameraPosition.addChildNode(camera)
```

And now the camera moving function looks like this:

```
func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: NSTimeInterval)
{
    var cameraP = SCNVector3(x: ball.presentationNode().position.x, y: ball.presentationNode().position.y + 5, z: ball.presentationNode().position.z + 12)
    cameraPosition.position = cameraP
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are adding a new constraint every time the ball touches anything, which probably happens a lot every frame!

Here's what you should do:

- Move the constraint creation to somewhere it will be only set once, such as the init
- Move the position update code to the [renderer delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRendererDelegate/renderer:didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:) so that it only get called once a frame, just after the physics have been calculated.

You should see a huge performance update!

Edit: try this

```
func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: NSTimeInterval){
    println("called")
}
```

Comment: edit: check question edit please. Can't format code properly in comment

Comment: I updated my answer. I accidentaly linked to the beta documentation and the variables where named differently.

Comment: Thanks to the new variable names I'm not getting the error, but the function is still not getting called and I'm not seeing "called" in the console. Not sure why its being ignored.

Comment: Where did you put this code? It needs to be in something comforming to `SCNSceneRendererDelegate`. You can see an example here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27849394/2053038

Comment: Alright. I added `, SCNSceneRendererDelegate` after `class ViewController: UIViewController, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate` and I'm not getting any errors, but the `println` still fails to execute.

Comment: I made it work by adding `sceneView.delegate = self`!. However, I must still remove the camera constraint before changing the position and then add it afterwards again so that the camera changes position. Thus, it hasn't really solved the problem.

Comment: How about putting the camera in a new `SCNNode`? Set the constraint on the camera and simply move the new node. Since the camera will be a child it should move as well.

Comment: That is precisely what I'm doing. The camera is a separate node that initially has a lookAt constraint. However I found out that when I try to change the position of a camera that has set constraint, it won't allow me to do so. That's why in my function I always remove the constraint before changing theorist ion and then I add the constraint back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83569/discussion-between-moustach-and-user2874028).